# Why isn't my segue being performed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I have a segue that should take place when one of a number of things happen, so it's called programatically, like so:

```
- (void)unwindAway
{
    NSLog(@"Let's segue");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
    NSLog(@"We should have just performed the segue");
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Let's do a segue");
}
```

but the output I get in the console is:

```
2014-05-29 22:20:30.173 My App[7848:60b] Let's segue
2014-05-29 22:20:30.178 My App[7848:60b] We should have just performed the segue
```

so as you can see, it's not even calling prepareForSegue.

The segue name is correct - if I give an invalid segue name it errors as you'd expect.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013591-CH1-UNWINDPROC

Comment: I'd double-check the spelling of the `IBAction` unwind method (and its signature should look like `- (IBAction)unwindActionNameHere:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;`) in the destination view controller and the spelling of that in the unwind segue in the storyboard. Note, it's case-sensitive. If it doesn't find a method of the appropriate name within the view controller hierarchy, the `performSegueWithIdentifier` will silently fail.

Comment: It might help to know what class implements the code you posted, how `unwindAway` is being called, and how **mySegue** is configured (i.e., what are the source and destination VCs)?

Comment: That code is all from one view controller (the one I'm leaving, since that's where I'm calling performSegueWithIdentifier).  That method, unwindAway, is selected as the target of a button and some other things.  I don't quite see how that matters though, we can see from the log that unwindAway is being called, but not prepareForSegue.

Comment: I'll check that the destination method of the segue is correct.  If that would cause a silent failure that might explain it!

Comment: It was indeed a problem with the destination method of the segue.  I don't know what the problem was as it looked right, I'd selected it through the menu in the interface builder so I couldn't have had a typo, but after typing it in instead it works :)  Some org of error in the console would have been handy Apple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Rob's suggestion in the comments I checked the name of the method in the destination View Controller in the segue.  It looked right (and was selected in IB rather than typed) but pasting over it and recompiling fixed the problem.  Something must have been messed up in the source code of the storyboard, perhaps an artefact of renaming methods.

It's worth noting if anyone has a similar issue that the app won't generate any error if the destination method of a segue isn't found anywhere (I've confirmed this by typing a nonsense method name).

Answer (score 2):

For unwind segues, `prepareForSegue:sender:` is called on the view controller that was the source of the segue, in other words the one you're exiting from.

Comment: Right.  It doesn't do much good for `prepareForSegue:sender:` to be called on the destination view controller of any segue.

Answer (score 0):

I know that your issue has been fixed, but for future reference I just want to say that similar problems might be caused by the way the unwind process works (zie the technical note link above).

As soon as the segue has been triggered in a certain view controller, its parent (!) view controller is called with the message: `viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:fromViewController:withSender:`. The implementation checks if the parent wants to handle the unwind action. If not, it's array with child view controllers is searched for a view controller that wants to handle the action.

My problem was that the unwind action was implemented in a child view controller of a view controller that was embedded in a navigation controller. So, when te segue began, the navigation controller (the parent) was asked: will you handle the action? It returned NO. Then, it's children were asked the same. It returned NO. Because the message isn't sent to a child view controller of a child of the parent view controller, there isn't a view controller that will handle the unwind action and it is aborted without an error message.

My solution was to implement the unwind action in the view controller itself and not in it's child view controller.